# Background of View inside UITableView which is inside UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios5, uitableview

I have a UITableView inside UITableViewCell. The inner tableview is of size 5 with each cell contentview of different background color and is editable.I'm able to reorder the tableviewcells of inner tableview.

I have a custom backgroundview for outer UITableViewCell.

```
 UIView *selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
 selectedBackgroundView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
 selectedBackgroundView.layer.borderWidth = 1;
 selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectedBackgroundView;
```

When I select the tableviewcell, the bg color of tableviewcells of inner tableview changes to white.

//CellForRow code of Parent TableView

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    TableViewCellCustom *cell = (TableViewCellCustom *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableViewCellCustom" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = _tableViewCellCustom;

        UIView *selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        selectedBackgroundView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
        selectedBackgroundView.layer.borderWidth = 1;
        selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectedBackgroundView;
    }

    CustomPosition *customPosition = [_filteredArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [cell setProductsArray: customPosition.productsArray];//Sets the products and reloads child tableview

    return cell;
}
```

//CellForRow of Child Tableview

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    TableViewCellProduct *cell = (TableViewCellProduct *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableViewCellProduct" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = _tableViewCellProduct;

        cell.viewProduct.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(cell.viewProduct.transform, M_PI_2);
    }

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            cell.viewProduct.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
            break;

        case 1:
            cell.viewProduct.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            break;

        case 2:
            cell.viewProduct.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
            break;

        case 3:
            cell.viewProduct.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
            break;

        case 4:
            cell.viewProduct.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    Product *product = [_productsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lblProductName.text = product.name;

    return cell;
}
```

Child tableview is rotated because i wanted horizontal tableview.

Anyone knows what is the solution for this?

Comment: post cellForRowAtIndexPath method code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a table view cell is selected the framework goes through all subviews and changes thier background colour to `UIColor clearColor`. This is so that the background colour of the table view cell can be seen properly. Usually this is what you want.

If it isn't what you want, you need to subclass `UITableViewCell` so that, after selection, you can restore the background colour of all of the subviews. Or manage the result of the selection entirely yourself.

Comment: Thanks. Instead of providing selectionBackground in cellForRowAtIndexPath:, I'm setting it in setSelected method of UITableViewCell subclass.